# magnifying glass for UITextField/UITextView -- what is it?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview, selection

If you touch and hold on a UITextField or UITextView, a magnifying glass appears above it, with the text, but magnified.  I'm trying to find it in the view hierarchy of my app.  But I can't.  What is it, and where is it located?  Presumably a private class somewhere -- I know I can't mess with it in an app store submission -- but it should still have a class name and exist somewhere in the hierarchy.  But what and where?